# Exception when I use Apache spark on a large Dataset

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

So I get the following exception when I run some mapping and filtering on a relatively large dataset (~1 MB)  using PySpark 1.4 in my local windows machine. I have tried using Apache Spark 1.6 and 2.0 and get the exact same exception.

However, if my data-set is small(~100 lines), the code works without any problem.

I have installed Apache Spark on my laptop and have decent amount of storage space and RAM. I tried increasing the memory allocation for spark but it still throws the error. Please help!

```
   Input File: c:/sparklocal/data/in/Emp/est12.txt
16/09/29 15:32:58 ERROR PythonRDD: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.app
ly(PythonRDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scal
a:208)
16/09/29 15:32:58 ERROR PythonRDD: This may have been caused by a prior exceptio
n:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.app
ly(PythonRDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scal
a:208)
16/09/29 15:32:58 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.app
ly(PythonRDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scal
a:208)
16/09/29 15:32:58 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; abor
ting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/sparklocal/py/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    header = tv_platform_textslines.first()
  File "c:\sparklocal\spark\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pys
park\rdd.py", line 1295, in first
  File "c:\sparklocal\spark\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pys
park\rdd.py", line 1277, in take
  File "c:\sparklocal\spark\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pys
park\context.py", line 897, in runJob
  File "c:\sparklocal\spark\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-sr
c.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "c:\sparklocal\spark\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-sr
c.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.
api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in s
tage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0,
 localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write er
ror
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.app
ly(PythonRDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scal
a:208)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DA
GScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(D
AGScheduler.scala:1264)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(D
AGScheduler.scala:1263)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.
scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala
:1263)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$
1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$
1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGSchedu
ler.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAG
Scheduler.scala:1457)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAG
Scheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Comment: can you elaborate by showing the command used to run the script.

Comment: I used the following command : 

spark-submit --master local[4] c:\sparklocal\py\test.py

Comment: can you try running the code with local[*] instead of local[4]?

Comment: And can you show code? :)

Comment: Basically all I am doing is reading a 2 MB text file and the using the .count() operation. Looks like it worked for a 900 KB file but not for 2 MB file using local[*]

Comment: `16/09/29 15:32:58 ERROR PythonRDD: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)`

Is what happened to you. You need to look at the executor or python interpreters they run to figure out what's going on. My gut guess is this is a low ram machine and the python process got OOM killed. But that's just a wild guess.

Comment: check the memory and CPU usage for (docker, vm or spark process) based on how you are running spark. if it's getting two high, more than allocated, this could be reason. try increasing the memory/CPU then,